# An Identity for a Fibbonacci-Type Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, function-and-relation-composition

### **Problem:**

The polynomials $p_{n}\left(x\right)$ are defined recursively by the linear homogenous order 2 difference equation $$p_{n+1}\left(x\right)=2\left(1-2x\right)p_{n}\left(x\right)-p_{n-1}\left(x\right)$$ and the initial conditions $p_{0}\left(x\right)=0$ and $p_{1}\left(x\right)=1$, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and any number $x$ in a field not of characteristic 2.

Show that 
$$p_{n+1}\left(x\right)+p_{n}\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}}$$

***Please note:** I would like to avoid using the following in the solution of the problem: trigonometric functions, chebyshev polynomials, analysis, generating functions, complex numbers. I would like to find an algebraic or combinatorial proof, but could settle for an induction/recursion solution.

### **My work so far:**

I found that there are a few ways to go about it, but the following seems the simplest.

Denote $1-x \equiv a$ and $x \equiv b$ and obtain $a+b=1$. Using this notation we will rewrite the above difference equation as $$p_{n+1}\left(x\right)=2\left(a-b\right)p_{n}\left(x\right)-\left(a+b\right)p_{n-1}\left(x\right)$$ and by using it iteratively obtain $$p_{n+1}\left(x\right)+p_{n}\left(x\right)=\left(3a-b\right)\left(p_{n}\left(x\right)+p_{n-1}\left(x\right)\right)-\left(2\right)\left((2a)p_{n-1}\left(x\right)\right)=\left(5a^2-10ab+b^2\right)\left(p_{n-1}\left(x\right)+p_{n-2}\left(x\right)\right)-\left(4a-4b\right)\left((2a)p_{n-2}\left(x\right)\right)=\left(7a^3-35a^{2}b+21ab^2-b^3\right)\left(p_{n-2}\left(x\right)+p_{n-3}\left(x\right)\right)-\left(6a^2-20ab+6b^2\right)\left((2a)p_{n-3}\left(x\right)\right)=\left(9a^4-84a^{3}b+126a^{2}b^2-36ab^3+b^4\right)\left(p_{n-3}\left(x\right)+p_{n-4}\left(x\right)\right)-\left(8a^3-56a^{2}b+56ab^2-8b^3\right)\left((2a)p_{n-4}\left(x\right)\right)$$ ...and so on. From the above I give the following guess for $1 \leq k \leq n$ $$p_{n+1}\left(x\right)+p_{n}\left(x\right)=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2k+1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{k-i}x^{i}}\right)\left(p_{n-k+1}\left(x\right)+p_{n-k}\left(x\right)\right)-\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2k}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{k-1-i}x^{i}}\right)\left((2a)p_{n-k}\left(x\right)\right)$$ so for $k=n$ we should obtain what we want to show. I may just have some mental block, but I wasn't able to formulate an inductive/recursive argument to prove this. My wish is to find an algebraic or combinatorial proof, but formaluting an inductive/recursive argument should be a good start.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It does not seem to be so. Do you ask becuase I used the "fibbonacci-type" term to discribe these polynomials? By reading a few papers I came to realize the term is used quite losely.

Comment: No, I just wanted to make sure you do not mean the famous Legendre polynomials. Please ignore my comment.

Comment: hint:

consider the sequences $r_n\left(x\right)=p_{n+1}\left(x\right)+p_{n}\left(x\right)$ and $q_n\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}}$.
Clearly $r_n$ obey the same linear homogenous order 2 recurrence as $p_n$. It is not too difficult to see that so does $q_n$. Then, in order to establish that $r_n=q_n$ for all $n$, it suffices that they coincide at $n=0$ and $n=1$, which is an easy check.

Comment: @RenéGy That's cute, I like it. May I have one additional hint for the "It is not too difficult to see that so does $q_n$" (a hint for a short way not dealing with double sums)?

Comment: see the answer I have just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another answer that should meet the OP requirements, but it is quite lengthy.

\begin{align*} \text{Let }q_n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}} \\
\text{and }a_n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}} \\
q_{n+1}&=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+3}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n+1-i}x^{i}} \\
\text{but } \binom{2n+3}{2i+1}&= \binom{2n+1}{2i+1}+2\binom{2n+1}{2i}+\binom{2n+1}{2i-1}\\
\text{then } q_{n+1}&=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n+1-i}x^{i}} + \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i-1}\left(1-x\right)^{n+1-i}x^{i}}\\ 
&+2 \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i}\left(1-x\right)^{n+1-i}x^{i}}\\
&=(1-x)\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}} - x\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}}\\ 
&+2 \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i}\left(1-x\right)^{n+1-i}x^{i}}\\
q_{n+1}&=(1-2x)q_n+ 2(1-x)a_n\\
\ \\
\color{red}{\text{that is }q_{n+1}+q_n}&\color{red}{=2(1-x)(q_n+a_n)}\\
\ \\
\text{but } \binom{2n+1}{2i}&=\binom{2n-1}{2i}+2\binom{2n-1}{2i-1}+\binom{2n-1}{2i-2}\\
\text{then } a_n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n-1}{2i}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}} + \sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n-1}{2i-2}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}}\\ 
&+2 \sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n-1}{2i-1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}}\\
&=(1-x)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n-1}{2i}\left(1-x\right)^{n-1-i}x^{i}} - x\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n-1}{2i}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i-1}x^{i}}\\ 
&+2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n-1}{2i-1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}}\\
&=(1-2x)a_{n-1}-2x \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n-1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-1-i}x^{i}}\\
a_n&=(1-2x)a_{n-1}-2x q_{n-1}\\
\ \\
\color{red}{\text{that is }a_{n+1}-a_{n}}&\color{red}{=-2x(a_{n}+ q_{n})}\\
\ \\
 \end{align*}

Then by substracting the two red lines
  \begin{align*} 
q_{n+1}-a_{n+1}&=q_n+a_n\\
q_{n+1}+a_{n+1}&=q_{n+2}-a_{n+2}\\
2q_{n+1}&=q_n+q_{n+2}+a_n-a_{n+2}\\
 \end{align*} 
 but also 
   \begin{align*} 
a_{n+2}-a_{n}&=a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}-a_{n} \\
&=-2x(a_{n+1}+q_{n+1})-2x(a_{n}+q_{n})\\
&=-2x(a_{n+1}+q_{n+1})-2x(q_{n+1}-a_{n+1})\\ 
&=-4xq_{n+1}\\ 
 \end{align*} 
  Then 
   \begin{align*} 
2q_{n+1}&=q_n+q_{n+2}+a_n-a_{n+2}\\
&=q_n+q_{n+2}+4xq_{n+1}\\
 \end{align*}
 which is the desired result.

Comment: Very nice. Kudos. Can you elaborate on the heuristics and/or intuition that led you to that answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$Q_n=\frac{\left(\sqrt{1-x}+{\bf I }\sqrt{x}\right)^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{x}}$$
where ${\bf I}^2 =-1$.

It can be seen with the binomial theorem that 
$$q_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\left( -1\right)^{i}\binom{2n+1}{2i+1}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}x^{i}}  $$ is the imaginary part of $Q_n$.

We then clearly have 
\begin{align}
Q_{n+1}&=Q_n \left(\sqrt{1-x}+{\bf I }\sqrt{x}\right)^{2}\\
Q_{n-1}&=Q_n \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{1-x}+{\bf I }\sqrt{x}\right)^{2}}
\end{align}
This gives readily 
\begin{align}
Q_{n+1}+Q_{n-1}&=Q_n \cdot 2\cdot \left(\sqrt{1-x}^2-\sqrt{x}^{2}\right)\\
&=2(1-2x)Q_n
\end{align}
And so $q_n$ obey the same order 2 linear recurrence as $p_n$. Since obviously $r_n=p_{n+1}+p_n$ also obey the same order 2 linear recurrence as $p_n$, in order to prove that $q_n= p_{n+1}+p_{n}$, it suffices to check that \begin{align} q_0&=1=p_0+p_1\\q_1&=3-4x= r_1  \\ \text{ since  }r_1&=p_2+p_1=2(1-2x)+1=3-4x. \end{align}

Comment: A very good effort. Unfortunately what I meant by "avoiding complex numbers" was that I had wanted to avoid objects like ${\bf I}$; square roots of non-square expressions are also something I want to avoid. I should have made that more clear, I apologize.

Comment: @Hellbound Ok, I have just posted another answer that should comply with your request.